# How to create tables with grouped elements using ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

How to create tables with grouped elements using ES6

I have objects in array:

```
  [ { keyOne: 1 } 
  , { keyOne: 2, keyTwo  :  3 } 
  , { keyOne: 2, keyThree:  2 } 
  , { keyOne: 4, keyFour : 32 } 
  ]
```

if KeyOne has the same key and value I will create a new array:
output:

In other words, I want to get groupings of objects based on values of a particular key.

```
  [ [ { keyOne: 1 }] 
  , [ { keyOne: 2, keyTwo :  3 }, { keyOne: 2, keyThree: 2 }] 
  , [ { keyOne: 4, keyFour: 32 }] 
  ]
```

Comment: So basically you need to group elements by the `KeyOne` key and put grouped elements into the subarray. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right :)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you just want an array of arrays of objects where all object in one array are grouped by one key name.

So, as a solution to your problem, I've made a function that will take the array and the keyname as parameters and return the groupings.

```js
const givenArr = [{KeyOne: 1,KeyTwo:2},{KeyOne:2, KeyTwo:3}, {KeyOne:2,KeyTwo: 2, KeyThree:2}, {KeyOne: 4,KeyTwo: 3, KeyFour:32}]



const getGroupingsByKey = (arr,key) => {

 let valueToArrayMap = {};
 arr.forEach(obj => {
  if(!valueToArrayMap[obj[key]]){
   valueToArrayMap[obj[key]] = [];
  }
  valueToArrayMap[obj[key]].push(obj);
 })
 return Object.keys(valueToArrayMap).reduce((targetArr,currentKey) => {
  targetArr.push(valueToArrayMap[currentKey]);
  return targetArr;
 },[]);
}

console.log("Group by KeyOne\n",getGroupingsByKey(givenArr,"KeyOne"));
console.log("Group by KeyTwo\n",getGroupingsByKey(givenArr,"KeyTwo"));
```

Please do let me know if it does not solve your problem so I can improve on it.

Answer (score 1):

you are supposed to show some of your essays ...
and pay attention to your variable names, Javascript is case sensitive ( [{**k**eyOne: 1},{**K**eyOne:2, )

```js
const data = 
      [ { keyOne: 1 } 
      , { keyOne: 2, keyTwo  : 3 } 
      , { keyOne: 2, keyThree: 2 } 
      , { keyOne: 4, keyFour : 32} 
      ] 

const result = data.reduce((a,c)=>
                {
                if (a.some(e=>e.some(l=>l.keyOne===c.keyOne)))
                  { (a.find(e=>e[0].keyOne===c.keyOne)).push( {...c} ) }
                else
                  { a.push( [ {...c} ] ) }   
                return a
                }, [])


result.forEach((r,i)=>console.log(`${i} -> ${ JSON.stringify(r)}`))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; background-color: turquoise; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a faster solution

```
[...new Set(data.map(({ keyOne }) => keyOne))].map(a => data.filter(({keyOne}) => a === keyOne))
```